Azure Batch Development and Testing Workflow
For anyone who is using Azure Batch.  What's your development and testing process when it comes to using Azure Batch with your application(s)?
I've come up with a solution using Azure Batch that caters for our needs well.  It gives us appropriate management because we can stop and restart Batch Jobs when necessary, and we can monitor our jobs using proven monitoring services in place.  However, my development team want to be able to develop and test locally in an End 2 End manner, using their local application instance.  For this to work, it means the nodes on Azure Batch need to be able to access the local instances on a devs machine.  I'm fairly confident that this is NOT the way to work when using a service such as Azure Batch, but I'd like to know if there's any other experiences out there?
